# transform using a shell script a formated xml file into a one-line file containing all the tags

Tags: xml, parsing, shell, grep

I have this xml file:

```
<content>
     <tag1>
          <innertag1>foo</innertag1>
          <innertag2>baa</innertag2>
     </tag>
     <tag2>
          <innertag1>foo2</innertag1>
          <innertag2>baa1</innertag2>
     </tag2>
</content>
```

and I need, using a script, another file with the same info but in one single line:

```
<content><tag1><innertag1>foo</innertag1><innertag2>baa</innertag2></tag><tag2><innertag1>foo 2</innertag1><innertag2>baa 1</innertag2></tag2></content>
```

because I need this format to use grep and sed commands. How can I do it?

thanks

Comment: You don't. You use a proper tool such as xmlstarlet.

Comment: this would great but I can't use additional tools, just the main ones. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tr -d '\n\t' inputfile > temp && echo >> temp && mv temp inputfile
```

or

```
sed -in ':a;$s/[\n\t]//g;N;ba' inputfile
```

for picky versions of `sed`:

```
sed -n  -e ':a' -e '$s/[\n\t]//g' -e 'N' -e 'ba' inputfile > temp && echo >> temp && mv temp inputfile
```

another option:

```
perl -i -pe 'chomp unless eof; s/\t//g' inputfile
```

or possibly:

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless eof; s/\t//g' inputfile > temp && echo >> temp && mv
```

**Edited to also remove tabs from the input file.**

Comment: I've tried your suggestions but the sed one says -i is an illegal option. If I remove it, the next msg is that the label ':a;$s/\n//g;N;ba' is greater than eight characters. Maybe we are using an old version.    The perl one does nothing to my file, maybe another version problem.  Finally I managed to get something with the tr one. It gives me a single line but with tabs so I guess I should do another delete of /t.

Comment: is there a way to add both restrictions ( '\n' and '\t' ) to the tr command? I'm trying to simplify it.  @Dennis, thanks by the way.

Comment: @Julian: `tr -d '\n\t'` (it looks at each character individually). What operating system are you using? You may have to use a temporary file with the `sed` version in the same manner as the `tr` version. Your `sed` command may need to be something like: `sed -n -e ':a' -e '$s/\n//g' -e 'N' -e 'ba' inputfile > temp ...`. I'm sorry, by the way, I completely overlooked the whitespace at the beginning of some lines. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: sorry, I didn't answer the os question. It's IBM AIX 5

Answer (score 0):

What about plain old regular expressions? `s/>\s*</></g`?

Comment: `\s` doesn't include newlines in `sed`.

Comment: @Dennis, yeah. I've meant PCRE `\s` and its usage with some tool (f.i. with `sed` with necessary modifications). But your answer is more complete and provides the script.